# Database Driver MySQLi Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am running Moodle test environment on Window Vista having PHP 5.2.10 and MySQL 5.1.36-Community.  When I upgrade from Moodle 1.9.9 to 2.0, I am getting the following error.

```
Error: database driver problem detected

The site administrator should verify server configuration

PHP has not been properly configured with the MySQLi extension so that it can communicate with MySQL. Please check your php.ini file or recompile PHP. MySQLi extension is not available for PHP 4.
```

I also tried to change the dbtype='mysqli' in config.ini and still see same error.

I would really appreciate if you can provide some suggestion to resolve this error.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this error as well some time ago and it took me quite a while to figure out a way how to solve that. Basically all you need to do is add an extension to your php envoirment. The following solution fits to a Microsoft Windows Server 2003 running Apache and MySQL:

- Find out where your php folder is located on the server that moodle is running on. It is usually at c:\php.
- Open php.ini. Within the file you will find ;extension=php_mysqli.dll. Delete the semicolon.
- Save the file.
- Restart Apache and go to your Moodle website.

Here we go, you shold be fine from now on ;) hope this helped!!

Comment: For anyone else who encounters this issue: be sure to check the extension directory setting in the php.ini config file.  It may be set to "ext" by default, I had to change it to the full path "c:\php\ext" and restart Apache to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

For my case: make sure the modules are a) installed b)enabled in php.ini

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for an answer for LINUX

uncomment

;extension=mysqli.so

in 'Dynamic Extensions' section in file 'php.ini' located in php folder ('/etc/php/php.ini' in my case)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the following package `php-mysql` and then restart the Apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the following package php-mysql and then restart the Apache web server.This is resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After enabling mysqli extension in php.ini by removing the ';' from the following line:

```
;extension=mysqli
```

Nothing changed up to now. Then I saw a post on the net that said you have to install php-mysqlnd package. After installing it using following command the problem resolved:

```
sudo apt install php-mysqlnd
```

Answer (score 0):

I am Using Xammp and runing multiple PHP versions, I found I needed to update my `php.ini` file to point to the correct extension directory.

Find the key line:

```
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php-5460\ext" ;<--- make sure this is correct
```

Answer (score -1):

it is also connected to the OS path.
you should add the php installed path to the general paths line.
For this, This PC->Properties->Advanced system settings-> Enviroment variables->System variables->Path
select Edit button
select New button
Paste php installed directory #For example c:\php
save every windows
reload apache

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).